# Preserve linebreaks from Artisan::output in Laravel 9

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

My Controller code goes like this:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;

class ArtisanCommandController extends Controller
{
    public function artisan() {
        Artisan::call('print:datetime');
        print_r(Artisan::output());
    }
}
```

Command.php:

```php
...
public function handle()
    {
        $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $this->alert($date);
        return 0;
    }
```

When I run `php artisan print:datetime` in CMD, I get a nice line-breaked output of the actual time:

```
*******************************
*     2022-08-18 12:29:43     *
*******************************
```

But when I try to run it from Controller, it prints out as a one-line text:

```
******************************* * 2022-08-18 12:29:43 * *******************************
```

Is there a way to print it as a multiple-line text?
When I do `dd(Artisan::output());`. I see all the `\n` line breaks..

Comment: Have you tried `echo` instead of `print_r`?

Comment: Yes, it does exactly the same..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run it in the controller you presumably see the results in the browser and the browser will not render CRLF as newlines. To have the browser show the text as "preformatted" you can wrap it in `<pre>` tags:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;

class ArtisanCommandController extends Controller
{
    public function artisan() {
        Artisan::call('print:datetime');
        return response('<pre>'.Artisan::output().'</pre>');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class callArtisan extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'print:datetime';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Command description';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        Artisan::call('ArtisanCommandController@artisan');       
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public function artisan() {
        $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');            
        return $date;
    }
```